# jgroup members can't join?

Tags: ehcache, jgroups

I use a ehcache that distributes via jgroups. I use UDP multicat for the distribution.

The ehcache lives within a webapp. There are several machines that run that webapp. For some reason I get a WARN NAKACK. Seems that the several instances of the ehcache can't join to a jgroup.

This is the ehcache config (containing the jgroups-config):

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="connect=UDP(mcast_addr=${ehcache.multicast.address};mcast_port=45566;ip_ttl=32;
        mcast_send_buf_size=150000;mcast_recv_buf_size=80000):
        PING(timeout=2000;num_initial_members=6):
        MERGE2(min_interval=5000;max_interval=10000):
        FD_SOCK:VERIFY_SUSPECT(timeout=1500):
        pbcast.NAKACK(gc_lag=10;retransmit_timeout=3000):
        UNICAST(timeout=5000):
        pbcast.STABLE(desired_avg_gossip=20000):
        FRAG:
        pbcast.GMS(join_timeout=5000;join_retry_timeout=2000;
        shun=false;print_local_addr=true)"
    propertySeparator="::" />
```

This is the stack trace:

```
TRACE - UDP                        - received [dst: <null>, src: testforce-54850 (2 headers), size=0 bytes, flags=OOB], headers are PING: [PING: type=GET_MBRS_REQ, cluster=EH_CACHE, arg=own_addr=testforce-54850, view id=null, is_server=false, is_coord=false, logical_name=testforce-54850, physical_addrs=fe80:0:0:0:216:3eff:fea6:7808%2:35176], UDP: [channel_name=EH_CACHE]
TRACE - PING                       - received GET_MBRS_REQ from testforce-54850, sending response [PING: type=GET_MBRS_RSP, arg=own_addr=hitchhiker-12009, view id=[hitchhiker-12009|0], is_server=true, is_coord=true, logical_name=hitchhiker-12009]
TRACE - UDP                        - sending msg to testforce-54850, src=hitchhiker-12009, headers are PING: [PING: type=GET_MBRS_RSP, arg=own_addr=hitchhiker-12009, view id=[hitchhiker-12009|0], is_server=true, is_coord=true, logical_name=hitchhiker-12009], UDP: [channel_name=EH_CACHE]
TRACE - UDP                        - received [dst: <null>, src: testforce-54850 (2 headers), size=0 bytes, flags=OOB], headers are PING: [PING: type=GET_MBRS_REQ, cluster=EH_CACHE, arg=own_addr=testforce-54850, view id=null, is_server=false, is_coord=false, logical_name=testforce-54850, physical_addrs=fe80:0:0:0:216:3eff:fea6:7808%2:35176], UDP: [channel_name=EH_CACHE]
TRACE - PING                       - received GET_MBRS_REQ from testforce-54850, sending response [PING: type=GET_MBRS_RSP, arg=own_addr=hitchhiker-12009, view id=[hitchhiker-12009|0], is_server=true, is_coord=true, logical_name=hitchhiker-12009]
TRACE - UDP                        - sending msg to testforce-54850, src=hitchhiker-12009, headers are PING: [PING: type=GET_MBRS_RSP, arg=own_addr=hitchhiker-12009, view id=[hitchhiker-12009|0], is_server=true, is_coord=true, logical_name=hitchhiker-12009], UDP: [channel_name=EH_CACHE]
TRACE - UDP                        - received [dst: <null>, src: testforce-54850 (3 headers), size=0 bytes, flags=OOB], headers are GMS: GmsHeader[GET_DIGEST_REQ]: mbr=null, NAKACK: [MSG, seqno=30], UDP: [channel_name=EH_CACHE]
TRACE - NAKACK                     - hitchhiker-12009: received testforce-54850#30
WARN  - NAKACK                     - hitchhiker-12009: dropped message from testforce-54850 (not in xmit_table), keys are [hitchhiker-12009], view=[hitchhiker-12009|0] [hitchhiker-12009]
TRACE - STABLE                     - hitchhiker-12009: setting latest_local_digest from NAKACK: [hitchhiker-12009#3]
TRACE - STABLE                     - hitchhiker-12009: sending stable msg [hitchhiker-12009#3]
TRACE - NAKACK                     - sending hitchhiker-12009#4
TRACE - UDP                        - sending msg to null, src=hitchhiker-12009, headers are STABLE: [STABLE_GOSSIP]: digest is hitchhiker-12009: [0 : 3 (3)], NAKACK: [MSG, seqno=4], UDP: [channel_name=EH_CACHE]
TRACE - UDP                        - looping back message [dst: <null>, src: hitchhiker-12009 (3 headers), size=0 bytes, flags=OOB]
TRACE - UDP                        - received [dst: <null>, src: hitchhiker-12009 (3 headers), size=0 bytes, flags=OOB], headers are STABLE: [STABLE_GOSSIP]: digest is hitchhiker-12009: [0 : 3 (3)], NAKACK: [MSG, seqno=4], UDP: [channel_name=EH_CACHE]
TRACE - NAKACK                     - hitchhiker-12009: received hitchhiker-12009#4
TRACE - STABLE                     - hitchhiker-12009: handling digest from hitchhiker-12009 (0 votes):
mine:   [hitchhiker-12009#2]
other:  [hitchhiker-12009#3]
result: [hitchhiker-12009#2]
```

Any ideas what I can do about this?
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Your post is half year old now, anyway, in such a case you have to make sure that the servers are in the same physical network and the port that you use for udp communication is not blocked anywhere between them.

Comment: thx for your answer, but in the mean time, I solved the issue by using RMI instead of jGroups for replication.